dotnet run command throws "system cannot find the path specified" exception for certificate
In implementing the "dotnet run" command in my vscode terminal, I keep getting the "system cannot find the path specified" exception, specifically for the certificate.
Currently the only fix I have figured out is to delete all the environment variables for the program, restart my computer, and then rewrite the environment variables again - which is a pain to do every time I want to run my API program because there is quite a few environment variables - making it work perfectly as normal. (I checked for typos and stuff but there was nothing wrong.)
I was just seeing if anyone else had a similar issue and what they did to fix it.
Thank you :)
